# Get array length in a PHP class

Tags: php

I'm new to object oriented programming in PHP.
I made a simple order class with an array property.
The method orderLength is not working. I'm getting an error:

> Call to undefined method Order::count()

PHP:

```
<?php
    class Order {
        private $order = array();

        public function setOrder($wert) {
            foreach($wert as $value) {
                $this -> order[] = $value;
            }
        }

        public function orderLength() {
            $length = $this -> count(order);
            return $length;
        }

        public function returnOrder() {
            $value = $this -> order;
            return $value;
        }
    }

    $order = new Order;
    $order -> setOrder(array('Book1', 'Book2', 'Book3', 'Book4'));

    foreach ($order->returnOrder() as $value) {
        echo $value . " <br/>";
    }

    echo "The order length is: " . $order->orderLength();
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php

Comment: There is no `count` method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `$this->count(order)` you can try with:

```
$length = count($this->order);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just return the count of $order:

```
public function orderLength() {
    return count($this->order);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Count is a method, not a class property, try this :

```
$length = count($this->order);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you miske that line

```
$this -> count(order);
```

Your class has no member functions with the name `count`, so remove that:

```
this ->
```

Comment: What does *"miske"* mean?

Answer (score 0):

You have not defined a method count for your class. The way you have done it, it looks like you are calling the `count` method of your class, giving `order` as an argument.

```
$length=count($this->order);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value to the variable `$order` and then write the code for getting the count:

```
$order = $order -> setOrder(array('Book1', 'Book2', 'Book3', 'Book4'));
echo "The order length is: ".$order->orderLength();
```